# Filing a continuation to result infringement

Tags: patent-infringement, claims

Given the following scenario:
A patent issued to me is a prior art to patent filed by another company – I have the priority date. I can easily invalidate their patent but it does not mean that uses of their “patent” are infringing on my patent – since the claims are not worded in such way, since the examiner forced incorporation of dependent claims.

Since I filed continuations/CIPs based on the previous specifications (prior art to the other company “patent”) I can now file a continuation to my past patents, and based on the “old” specification, will include claims that will make uses of their “patent” infringing on that claim – my patents.
Will this work?

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_patent?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @Eric not relevant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - but focus on their product not necessarily their claims. If you have a live application type can either amend claims or file a continuation and craft claims that are both supported by your original application and read clearly on their product. It is products that infringe, not claims.

Comment: I fully understand what you say - I need this continuation filing because the design suggested by their patent is used in a certain product which is not infringing on my current claims. Thanks for verifying my thoughts.